# Crash on TF Detect app for some faster rcnn models.

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm training some faster rcnn models with only one class on 
my own data set. The training goes fine but when I export 
model for inference and try to used it on android sample app
(TF Detect), I'm getting the following exception:

11-28 10:56:27.002 15666 16593 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
11-28 10:56:27.002 15666 16593 E AndroidRuntime: Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 15666
11-28 10:56:27.002 15666 16593 E AndroidRuntime: java.nio.BufferOverflowException
11-28 10:56:27.002 15666 16593 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.nio.HeapFloatBuffer.put(HeapFloatBuffer.java:179)
11-28 10:56:27.002 15666 16593 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.tensorflow.Tensor.writeTo(Tensor.java:488)
11-28 10:56:27.002 15666 16593 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.fetch(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:478)
11-28 10:56:27.002 15666 16593 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.fetch(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:432)
11-28 10:56:27.002 15666 16593 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.tensorflow.demo.TensorFlowObjectDetectionAPIModel.recognizeImage(TensorFlowObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:167)

at the following line of code from TensorFlowObjectDetectionAPIModel class:

inferenceInterface.fetch(outputNames[0], outputLocations);

I tried these two models:

faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets
faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets

Do you have any idea about what is causing this exception?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I am using FasterRcnn, I've solved same issue by changing value of MAX_RESULTS from 100 to 500 in TensorFlowObjectDetectionAPIModel.java (TensorFlow android example app)

Problem is RCNN returns more output than SSD

Sorry, this is my first answer

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution to my issue as well. In their code, the value of max_results was set to 100. When I tried to decrease it I have had still the same error, but when I set it up to 500 no exception overflow was raised, the application is working. Thanks!